# Is the Prism dll's for Silverlight and Desktop the same set of dll's?

Tags: silverlight, prism

Are the prism dll's the same for both platforms?

If so, im assuming them to be Silverlight assemblies since Silverlight (the last i checked) can not reference non-silverlight assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest Prism-v4 drop, the assemblies are different for WPF & Silverlight.

Thanks,
Damian